# How do I use Arabic script in external packages such as pdfmarkupcomment?

Tags: arabic, tooltips

I've tried various different solutions and packages but they all fail to achieve what I'm after, which is to display some Arabic with a tooltip in English.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic]{DejaVu Sans}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
    Arabic tooltip test.
    
    Works fine outside:
    
    \begin{txarab}الكتابة العربية\end{txarab}

    But not inside a comment (another command):
    
    \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Underline]{ \begin{txarab}الكتابة العربية\end{txarab} }{Test}
    
\end{document}
```

So the above (via TeXstudio/lualatex) gives a bunch of errors - too many to list here (but, as an example: `Environment {txarab} undefined. ...تابة العربية\end{txarab} }{Test}`) - so it appears that it's falling over because it cannot recognise the Arabic that is being provided to the `\pdfmarkupcomment` command.

I've even tried with setting the main language to be Arabic and the other language English but to no avail.

So is there a way around this, so that I can pass some Arabic to the `\pdfmarkupcomment` command, or any other command for that matter, or is that a limitation of this particular package?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you want DejaVu Sans for both English and Arabic, use `\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}` and `\newfontfamily\arabicfont{DejaVu Sans}[Script=Arabic]` (TeX ligatures are on by default).

Comment: Thanks @Thérèse. Every little helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pdfcomment uses the soul package to allow line breaks in the text, but soul is really not suitable for arabic and it doesn't like the environment.

It works if you put a box around the arabic:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Script=Arabic]{DejaVu Sans}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Underline]{\mbox{\begin{txarab}الكتابة العربية\end{txarab}}}{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Really appreciate your help. Thanks